# Problem Iterating through a 2d array using nested for loop and returning index

Tags: python, loops, indexing

We need to write a function called `whereCanIPark()` that returns the coordinates of an available parking spot for the vehicle, or returns false if there is no available spot. Our function receives a list of lists representing parking spots, and a string with type of the vehicle that is looking for a parking spot.

There are three kinds of possible vehicles: regular cars, small cars, and motorcycles.

Regular cars can only park in R spots.
Small cars can park in R or S spots.
Motorcycles can park in R, S, or M spots.
In the list of parking spots, spots are written in both lower-case and upper-case. An upper-case letter means that the particular spot is AVAILABLE, while lower-case letters mean that the spot is UNAVAILABLE.

Our function must return a list with the coordinates of the spot as an `[X, Y]` pair. The code I have written with a test is below:  It should print the co-ordinates `4,0` but I am getting `False`.

```
def whereCanIPark(spots, vehicle):
    for y in spots:
        for x in spots:
            
            if vehicle == "regular" and spots == "R":
                return [x,y]

            elif vehicle == "small" and spots == "S" or spots == "R":
                return [x,y]

            elif vehicle == "motorcycle" and spots == "S" or spots == "R" or spots == "M":
                return [x,y]
            else:
                return False

print(whereCanIPark(
  [
    # COLUMNS ARE X
    # 0    1    2    3    4    5
    ['s', 's', 's', 'S', 'R', 'M'], # 0 ROWS ARE Y
    ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'r', 'M'], # 1
    ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'r', 'm'], # 2
    ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'r', 'M'], # 3
    ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'r', 'M'], # 4
    ['S', 'r', 'S', 'M', 'M', 'S']  # 5
  ],
  'regular'
    ))
```

Comment: In your own words, when you do `vehicle == "regular" and spots == "R"`, do you expect that condition to ever be met? Why? (Hint: what is the value of `spots` at this point in the code? Is it a string?)

Comment: In your own words, when you do `for x in spots:` and then `for y in spots:` inside that, what do you expect the values of `x` to look like? What do you expect the value of `y` to look like? Now, *test that*. Are your expectations met? Why or why not?

Comment: In your own words, when you call a function, how many times is it possible to `return` from that same call to the function? What are the implications for your logic? Do you need to find *all* available spots, or just the *first* one?

Comment: Hi Karl, thank you for your questions.  I would think the condition would be met at the first capital R, at 4,0.  I am still trying to wrap my brain around functions, but would the values of x be a sublist.  I think it is only possible to return a function once and you are correct, we only need to find the first available spot.

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to diagnose what your code is doing and where that diverges from your expectations. There are multiple issues with the code here, each of which could be its own question if properly researched, but there are probably duplicates for those questions already.

Comment: Sorry I am really lost in this.  At this point I have just strung together a few small scale concepts that I have learned so far. It might help me wrap my brain around it if you could tell me how the first `if` statement might look for it to run correctly. I might be better able to understand its functionality?

Comment: " I would think the condition would be met at the first capital R, at 4,0" Why? Do you think that `spots` is equal to `"R"` at this point? Why? What was `spots` equal to at the beginning of the function? Has anything happened to change the value of `spots`?

Comment: "It might help me wrap my brain around it if you could tell me how the first if statement might look for it to run correctly." No; if you ever expect to fix your own code, then you need to start by learning to understand *what you actually wrote*.

Answer (score 0):

Your `spots` parameter is a list of lists but you seem to expect it to magically determine that you sometimes want it to give you coordinates (`for x in spots`, `for y in spots`) and sometimes contain a specific value (`if spots == 'R'`, ...).

You will need to use indexing (e.g. `spots[x][y]`) to get to individual values in the list of lists and ranges (or enumerate) to get indexes for rows and columns.